# Print function and numpy.savetxt in python 3

Tags: python, numpy

Some code I am using (not in python) takes input files written in specific way. I usually prepare such input files with python scripts. One of them takes the following format:

```
100
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

where 100 is just an overall parameter and the rest is a matrix. In python 2, I used to do it in the following way:

```
# python 2.7
import numpy as np
Matrix = np.arange(9)
Matrix.shape = 3,3
f = open('input.inp', 'w')
print >> f, 100
np.savetxt(f, Matrix)
```

I just converted to python 3 recently. Running above script with 2to3 gets me something like:

```
# python 3.6
import numpy as np
Matrix = np.arange(9)
Matrix.shape = 3,3
f = open('input.inp', 'w')
print(100, file=f)
np.savetxt(f, Matrix)
```

The first error I got was `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`, because there are something like `fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))` during the execution of `numpy.savetxt`. I was able to fix this problem through opening the file as a binary: `f = open('input.inp', 'wb')`. But this will cause the `print()` to fail. Is there a way to harmonize these two?

Comment: Are you sure you have a Numpy build intended to work with your current Python version?

Comment: Good question. I am using Anaconda to manage my python packages. In converting to python 3, I created a new environment with python 3.6, and then installed everything again in the new environment with something like `conda install numpy`. Is this sufficient?

Comment: `savetxt` opens its file with 'wb'` and passes all strings through `np.asbytes`, which does a `.encode('latin1')` on all unicode strings.  The idea is to maintain a Py2 style output.  The code is readable Python.

Comment: How about using the `header` parameter to write the text to the start of the file?  That way `savetxt` can care of the conversion to bytestring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same issue converting to python3. All strings in python3 are interpreted as unicode by default now, so you have to convert. I found the solution of writing to a string first and then writing the string to the file to be the most appealing. This is a working version of your snippet in python3 using this method:

```
# python 3.6
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np
Matrix = np.arange(9)
Matrix.shape = 3,3
f = open('input.inp', 'w')
print(100, file=f)
fh = BytesIO()
np.savetxt(fh, Matrix, fmt='%d')
cstr = fh.getvalue()
fh.close()
print(cstr.decode('UTF-8'), file=f)
```